# populate dataframe in specific manner

Tags: python, pandas

Consider a `pandas` Dataframe - `ratios_df` of dimensions (`n_days`, `m_sims`) as below:

|  | Date | sim-0 | sim-1 | sim-2 | sim-3 | sim-4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-04-04 | 1.002300672 | 0.990059844 | 0.983114717 | 0.992021836 | 1.000693493 |
| 1 | 2022-04-05 | 1.006260448 | 0.990298648 | 0.989395511 | 0.985853195 | 1.0257736 |
| 2 | 2022-04-06 | 0.9837654 | 0.982929937 | 0.997217298 | 1.025278723 | 1.004068435 |
| 3 | 2022-04-07 | 1.024906472 | 0.996442483 | 1.016851937 | 1.027790592 | 0.996677016 |
| 4 | 2022-04-08 | 1.002229742 | 0.977206326 | 1.000474398 | 1.010322048 | 0.996959044 |

What is best the pythonic way of populating another dataframe - `prices_df` as per below rules:

1. For first cell of each column, Multiply an `initial_value` with `ratio`
2. For subsequent cells in each column, multiply the `ratio` with cell value above it

Thus if `initial_value=1600`, then `prices_df` will be:

|  | Date | sim-0 | sim-1 | sim-2 | sim-3 | sim-4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-04-04 | 1603.681075 | 1584.09575 | 1572.983546 | 1587.234938 | 1601.109588 |
| 1 | 2022-04-05 | 1613.720837 | 1568.727879 | 1556.30286 | 1564.780635 | 1642.375947 |
| 2 | 2022-04-06 | 1587.522724 | 1541.949596 | 1551.972133 | 1604.336292 | 1649.057846 |
| 3 | 2022-04-07 | 1627.062315 | 1536.464085 | 1578.125869 | 1648.921747 | 1643.578053 |
| 4 | 2022-04-08 | 1630.690244 | 1501.442423 | 1578.874528 | 1665.941996 | 1638.580004 |

Comment: This question needs a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Always provide a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example"). Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @itprorh66 Thanks for suggestions. The question has been summerized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `DataFrame.cumprod`

```
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].cumprod().mul(initial_value)
```

---

```
         Date        sim-0        sim-1        sim-2        sim-3        sim-4
0  2022-04-04  1603.681075  1584.095750  1572.983547  1587.234938  1601.109589
1  2022-04-05  1613.720837  1568.727880  1556.302860  1564.780634  1642.375947
2  2022-04-06  1587.522725  1541.949596  1551.972133  1604.336291  1649.057847
3  2022-04-07  1627.062315  1536.464084  1578.125870  1648.921746  1643.578054
4  2022-04-08  1630.690244  1501.442423  1578.874530  1665.941995  1638.580005
```